# How to create this matrix in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am new in python and was struggling on how to code this matrix for a while.

```
x'=[x1,x2,x3,x4,...,xN]
```

x is the transpose of the above matrix.

I'd like to create a matrix y with values

[image: shown here]

x needs to be the input of y so that the value of x and k can be altered by users.

```
def(x,k)
```

How can I continue to code this matrix in Python?

Comment: Please do not use a link to an external image, type it in your question instead. Better use a reproducible example. Secondly, is x a list of lists, np.array or np.matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the following function.

```
def generate_poly_data(data,degree):
    first_row = np.ones((data.shape[0],1))

    poly_data = np.column_stack((first_row, data))
    for i in range(2,degree+1):
        poly_data = np.column_stack((poly_data,data**i))
    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
    return poly_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of writing the function. Let `base_vector` (your x) be a numpy array, and let `max_power` (your k) be an integer.

```
import numpy as np

def generate_poly_matrix(base_vector, max_power):
    poly_matrix = np.zeros((base_vector.size, max_power + 1))
    for (i, j), _ in np.ndenumerate(poly_matrix):
        poly_matrix[i, j] = base_vector[i]**j
    return poly_matrix
```

Here is another way, using different methods. Informal testing showed that these run in similar times.

```
def generate_poly_matrix2(base_vector, max_power):
    base_matrix = np.tile(base_vector, (max_power+1, 1)).T
    powers = np.arange(0, max_power+1)
    return np.power(base_matrix, powers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcasting to avoid explicit tiling.
Let `base_vector` (your x) be a numpy array, and let `max_power` (your k) be an integer as in @Eric Miller's answer.

```
import numpy as np

powers = np.range(max_power+1)
result = base_vector[:, np.newaxis] ** powers[np.newaxis, :]
```